# How to pass element as parameter to function

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Is there any way to pass an element as a parameter to the onclick (or any other) function, `without` defining a ref variable ?

Something like you would do in Angular for example `<button #myBtn (click)='foo(myBtn)'>`

The current way that I know how to achieve this in Blazor is a bit verbose.

```
<button @ref=MyButton @onclick='(()=>foo(MyButton))'>

@code{
 ElementReference MyButton;
}
```

I would like to get rid of the `@code` part if that is possible.

Comment: To give an intelligent answer, what does `foo` do that needs a reference?

Comment: JsInterop stuff, that needs the element for getting it's size, placement etc.

Comment: @The Backer 's has provided what would have been my answer, except I use Guids for id's these days for uniqueness.

Comment: That brings up the same problem. You still have to declare that ID property in code.  That's what I am also using as of now but I don't think it's optimal, especially when you need to do this on multiple elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do some JsInterop stuff, then you don't need @ref.

```
<button id="mybutton" @onclick='(()=>Foo("mybutton"))'>
```

on your Foo method:

```
        async Task Foo(string id)
        {
        //...do something before
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("doSomething ", id);
        //...do something after js function invoked
        }
```

on your Js:

```
doSomething = (id) => {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: I wanted the ref for simplicity's sake, as long as it worked the same way as in Angular. Having to deal with hundreds of elements in an app, I would use guids for Id uniqueness, and I would still have to declare the ID as a property. Your solution is indeed correct but it doesn't solve what I'm looking for. Referencing the element directly, or being able to pass the ID ( but as guid, not an imperatively declared one) without having to declare an extra property in code to hold that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass refence like that but it should filled or try to pass cascading parameter . It can reachable on parent to child .

You can create .cs file and  inherit it from ComponentBase  and also on component page you should inherit that base.

Example ComponentClass:   public class TextBoxComponentBase: ComponentBase

Example Component: @inherits TextBoxComponentBase
You will get rid of @code part like this .

Comment: This is just a small example. Imagine I have 10 elements in this component that need to be referenced.